# Who is this man in the cover page of One Piece chapter 839?

Tags: one-piece

In the cover page of chapter 839 of *One Piece*, there's a man on large bounty poster that Luffy draw number 3 on his face.

> [image: One Piece chapter 839 cover page]

It seems that all Mugiwara crew give some respect to this man, even
Chopper looks like he's crying for him.

I don't think he is the character on *One Piece*, is this some kind of tribute from Oda to someone? So, who is he?

Comment: He is Kankichi Ryotsu. As stated on http://onepiece.wikia.com/
Luffy paints Kankichi Ryotsu's signature eyebrows on a giant wanted poster of the character as he and the Straw Hats commemorate the ending of the manga Kochira Katsushika-ku Kameari Kōen-mae Hashutsujo. See [link](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_839)

Comment: @Nube1Nu2 Instead of posting your answer as a comment, you should post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is [Kankichi Ryotsu](http://kochikame.wikia.com/wiki/Kankichi_Ryotsu) from *Kochikame*.

Comment: So its a tribute to Kochikame for its ending :) Thats soo cool